# All values changes without breakpoints

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to put together at simple Yatsy game in wpf but have run into a strange problem. Basically when clicking the button reroll in the UI the UpdateLogic() Method is called. The method loop through the List of Dices and should update each value and the image link randomly and individually.

Here are the strange part. If I run it as usual in debug mode without breakboint or the released .exe file all the values and image-links always get the same value. If I run in debug mode with breakpoint and steps through the request for new values it works as expected.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
namespace Yatzy
{
```

`public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DiceManager dm;
    private List<BitmapImage> sidesToDisplay = new List<BitmapImage>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateObjects();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            var side = new BitmapImage();
            sidesToDisplay.Add(side);
            sidesToDisplay[i].BeginInit();
            sidesToDisplay[i].UriSource = new Uri(@"Images/Side" + (i+1) +".png", UriKind.Relative);
            sidesToDisplay[i].EndInit();
        }
    }

    private void CreateObjects()
    {
        dm = new DiceManager();
        dm.GenerateDices();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateLogic();
    }

    private void UpdateLogic()
    {
        foreach (Dice dice in dm.AllDices)
        {
            dice.SetNewValue(sidesToDisplay);
        }

        Dice1.Source = dm.AllDices[0].sideToDisplay;
        Dice2.Source = dm.AllDices[1].sideToDisplay;
        Dice3.Source = dm.AllDices[2].sideToDisplay;
        Dice4.Source = dm.AllDices[3].sideToDisplay;
        Dice5.Source = dm.AllDices[4].sideToDisplay;
    }
}

public class DiceManager
{
    public List<Dice> AllDices { get; set; }

    public DiceManager()
    {
        AllDices = new List<Dice>();
    }

    public void GenerateDices()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            AllDices.Add(new Dice());
        }
    }
}

public class Dice
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage sideToDisplay { get; set; }

    public void SetNewValue(List<BitmapImage> imageList)
    {
        Value = new Random().Next(1, 7);
        sideToDisplay = imageList[Value - 1];
    }
}`

}

Comment: Putting the creation of the Random instance inside a loop is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Random instance is initialized with a seed value that is taken from the system clock. This creates a problem when you create new Random instances inside a tight loop. These instances are generated using the same clock value and thus they give back the same sequence of numbers.

The trick is to create a Random instance one time for all your dices and call Next on this instance.

```
public class Dice
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage sideToDisplay { get; set; }

    public void SetNewValue(List<BitmapImage> imageList, int diceValue)
    {
        Value = diceValue;
        sideToDisplay = imageList[Value - 1];
    }
}

and in the UpdateLogic 

private void UpdateLogic()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    foreach (Dice dice in dm.AllDices)
    {
        dice.SetNewValue(sidesToDisplay, rnd.Next(1,7));
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: The debugging has the effect to loosen the tight loop so it is possible that in debug _sometime_ the code works if you stop long enough to give the clock the time to initialize the random with a different seed.

Comment: Thanks alot! Created me alot of confusion.